# Sitecore - create datasource parent "An error ocurred" SetSublayout

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I'm trying to get Sitecore to create a new item before the "Select Datasource" dialog that opens from the Page Editor when a new rendering is added to the page.

we are building a multi site solution where each site is represented like this (conceptual)

```
site1 (template = website)
    Datasources (template = datasourcefolder)
        Module X Sources (template = module1container)
            Module Source 1 (template = module1)
        Module Y Sources (template = module2container)
        ...
    Home (template = startpage)
```

The sites will be created using a branch template that will create the items based on templates website, datasourcefolder and startpage.

Here's what I want to happen:

When a new sublayout is added, check if the source exists, if not, create a new item in *site1/Datasources/[Module name]* based on a specified template (defined as *Parent Datasource Template* and added to the *Sublayout* template). Then add this new item to the dialog DatasourceRoots to allow the user to create datasource items below it.

I've successfully implemented a pipeline to check for, and create the item if it doesn't exist and the *Select rendering datasource* dialog shows the newly created item and allows the user to create a new datasource item below it, just as expected. However, after clicking OK, an alert is show with the message "An error occurred". Closing this dialog and performing the operation again (when the datasource root already exists) works just fine.

Using Reflector I have verified that the item created from the dialog (Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.SelectRenderingDatasourceForm) is returned properly and the dialog is closed with the correct arguments and a SetDialogValue call with the exepected item.

I guess my question is; what happens AFTER this dialog is closed? What pipeline is triggered to actually set the datasource on the rendering? I need to figure out where this error is raised and, of course, fix whatever is wrong...

I realize this might be a bit hard to understand, I'll gladly provide the code if needed.

Comment: can you check logs for the exception?

Comment: @Maras the logs show no errors (exceptions or warnings) whatsoever, unfortunately.

Comment: and if you attach with Visual Studio to the web app, does it show any error?

Comment: No, no errors in log or when debugging. I'm guessing it's not an error but rather a null check (or something similar) omitting a SheerResponse.Alert when failing (again, just guessing).

Comment: Could you paste the code of the pipeline which creates the datasources root and the url of the dialog for selecting the datasource? Can you try to create a datasource outside of the created root and check whether it works or fails as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something very similar, but as a child of the current item. Reference the code here:

https://github.com/techphoria414/pageeditor-unleashed/blob/master/PageEditor.Unleashed.Classes/Pipelines/GetRenderingDatasource/CreateContentFolder.cs

I would ensure you are using a SiteContextSwitcher when creating the item. Otherwise event handlers in place for the PageEditor could have unknown side-effects. Some of these event handlers are created in code by Sitecore, and can't be disabled in config.

Comment: The SiteContextSwitcher was what was missing! Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's an event that is causing the error, not a pipeline processor. Probably an OnItemSaving event.

By default, Sitecore has configured `Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaving` to be executed when an item is being saved.

Comment: Oh, that did not occur to me at all. I'll look in to that!

Comment: Ok, so I disabled all events in item:saved and item:saving but still seeing that "An error occurred" alert :(

Comment: Hmm.. then maybe it's one of the client pipelines, one in <saveUI> or <uiSaveLayout> for example

Comment: Disabled everything in saveUI and uiSaveLayout without any improvement.